# Mysql / PHP pivot tables filter

Tags: php, mysql

been trying this for days with no joy so thought Id ask the question?

I have a php pivot based on mysql query, it works great but I would like to have an external filter for years..Currently i can only include 2017 for example in the where clause, Ive tried to remove that but cant seem to work out how to have it display current years data on load then filter it by user input of year. Currenbtly I have 5 different tables for each year which is getting cumbersome, is this possible?

```
SELECT * FROM 
  (SELECT c.Adviser,
  Sum(Case When Month(i.signedupdate) = 1 Then i.comms + i.broker_fee + i.legal_fees Else 0 End) Jan,
  Sum(Case When Month(i.signedupdate) = 2 Then i.comms + i.broker_fee + i.legal_fees Else 0 End) Feb,
  Sum(Case When Month(i.signedupdate) = 3 Then i.comms + i.broker_fee + i.legal_fees Else 0 End) Mar,
  Sum(Case When Month(i.signedupdate) = 4 Then i.comms + i.broker_fee + i.legal_fees Else 0 End) Apr,
  Sum(Case When Month(i.signedupdate) = 5 Then i.comms + i.broker_fee + i.legal_fees Else 0 End) May,
  Sum(Case When Month(i.signedupdate) = 6 Then i.comms + i.broker_fee + i.legal_fees Else 0 End) Jun,
  Sum(Case When Month(i.signedupdate) = 7 Then i.comms + i.broker_fee + i.legal_fees Else 0 End) Jul,
  Sum(Case When Month(i.signedupdate) = 8 Then i.comms + i.broker_fee + i.legal_fees Else 0 End) Aug,
  Sum(Case When Month(i.signedupdate) = 9 Then i.comms + i.broker_fee + i.legal_fees Else 0 End) Sept,
  Sum(Case When Month(i.signedupdate) = 10 Then i.comms + i.broker_fee + i.legal_fees Else 0 End) Oct,
  Sum(Case When Month(i.signedupdate) = 11 Then i.comms + i.broker_fee + i.legal_fees Else 0 End) Nov,
  Sum(Case When Month(i.signedupdate) = 12 Then i.comms + i.broker_fee + i.legal_fees Else 0 End) Dece,
  Sum(i.comms + i.broker_fee + i.legal_fees) As Total
From
  tbl_lead i Inner Join
  tbl_clients c On c.client_id = i.client_id
Where
    Year(i.signedupdate)= 2017
Group By c.Adviser with rollup) As t
```

Comment: If you're calling this from PHP then surely you just need to switch out the hard-coded "2017" for a parameter which represents either a default of the current year (on start-up) or a value selected by the user? Do you know how to set SQL query parameters when executing SQL code from PHP?

Comment: If you want to have the YEAR edited within your query you need to create a PHP $_POST year which can be set in an input field or dropdown. Do you know how to do this?

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses much appreciated. As you may tell I'm learning as I go so will need to try and work out how to achieve that. Would I add something else to the where then call that in the select field on the page?

Comment: I don't think you need to add something else to the WHERE, instead it looks like you need to create a parameter instead of the literal "2017" string. Maybe a take a tutorial on parameterised queries with PHP/MYSQL.

Comment: Thank you, I had a look and can filter of sorts but not on the year as such as it doesn't really exist in the query, its all summed by month columns. If I add another column for YEAR(i.signedupdate) it breaks, cant quite work out why/where yet.

Comment: I don't follow you. Are you saying `Where
    Year(i.signedupdate)= 2017` in your sample above doesn't work?